# Displaying a Quicktime movie's Current Time & End Time with Javascript

Tags: javascript, quicktime

I have a Quicktime instance and I would like to create custom controls. Start, stop and Step forward and backwards were easy enough.

Q: How do I display Current time / End Time. Format: 01:12 / 02:45

I have read Apple's docs on GetTime() and GetEndTime() however I can not make the js work.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
        QT_WriteOBJECT_XHTML('{$mUrl|escape}' ,
                        '{$mdW}', '{$mdH}', '',
                        'emb#NAME', '{$mId}',
                        'obj#id', '{$mId}',
                        'AUTOPLAY', 'false',
                        'SCALE', 'Aspect',
                        'KIOSKMODE', 'true',
                        'MOVIENAME', '{$mName|escape}',
                        'CONTROLLER', 'false',
                        'EnableJavaScript', 'true',
                        'POSTDOMEVENTS', 'true',
                        'SHOWLOGO', 'true'
                        ) ;
    // ]]>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include [ac_quicktime_js](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/samplecode/HTML_video_example/Listings/ac_quicktime_js.html) in your html. `QT_WriteOBJECT` will create an object with the name you define in `emb#NAME`. Here is an example of how to use `GetTime()`.

```
<script src="ac_quicktime.js"></script>

<script>QT_WriteOBJECT('video.mov' ,'640', '510', '', 'emb#NAME' , 'movie1') ;</script>

<a href="#" onClick="alert( document.movie1.GetTime() )">Get the time</a>
```

Note that the whole plugin idea is considered outdated by current web standards. But the QuickTime plugin is still included in the latest OSX and I believe it's included with iTunes for Windows. It doesn't work on iOS.